# Como saber se o cursor está sobre um determinado componente em javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Eu tenho um componente em javaFX e gostaria de saber se o cursor está posicionado sobre o mesmo. Existe uma função para tal?

Eu tentei criar um `boolean` que armazena isso utilizando os eventos `setOnMouseEntered` e `setOnMouseExited`, porém eu uso isso para dois componentes e as *threads* dos eventos do java acabaram criando bugs (um evento terminava antes do outro).

Então gostaria de saber se tem algum método para saber se o cursor está sobre um componente quando o método é chamado.

Código:

```
public class BarraLogoffControlador implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private HBox menu;

    @FXML
    private Button botao_expandir;

    private final HBox painel = new HBox();
    private boolean esta_no_botao = false;
    private boolean esta_no_painel = false;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        Polygon seta = new Polygon(
                54.0, 52.0,
                54.0, 58.0,
                50.0, 55.0
        );

        this.menu.getStylesheets().add("/iftorrent/gui/barraLogoff/BarraLogoffCSS.css");
        this.menu.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        this.menu.setMinSize(0, 0);
        this.menu.setPrefHeight(ALTURA_BARRA_LOGOFF1);

        this.botao_expandir.setOnMouseEntered((Event event) -> {
            if(!menu.getChildren().contains(painel)){
                menu.getChildren().add(painel);
            }
            esta_no_botao = true;
        });

        this.painel.setOnMouseEntered((Event event) -> {
            esta_no_painel = true;
        });

        this.botao_expandir.setOnMouseExited((Event event) -> {
            esta_no_botao = false;
        });

        this.painel.setOnMouseExited((Event event) -> {
            esta_no_painel = false;
        });

        this.botao_expandir.setGraphic(seta);
        this.botao_expandir.setMinWidth(5);
        this.botao_expandir.setPrefWidth(8);
        this.botao_expandir.setMaxHeight(ALTURA_BARRA_LOGOFF1);
        this.painel.getChildren().addAll(
                new Button("desligar"),
                new Button("fechar"),
                new Button("bloquear")
        );
        this.painel.setId("painel");
        this.painel.setMaxHeight(ALTURA_BARRA_LOGOFF1);
        this.painel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Basicamente, a ideia é um componente com um botão no qual, ao posicionarmos o cursor, expande uma série de botões.

O código em `FXML` apenas cria uma HBox chamada menu e adiciona o `Button` botao_expandir dentro.

O problema é: o componente é composto por duas partes, um botão e uma hbox. Ao passarmos o mouse de um componente para outro, ele sai de um componente e entra em outro, chamando assim dois eventos. No evento de entrada, ele atualiza uma variável boolean que armazena se o cursor está sobre o componente, já no evento de saída, ele verifica se o cursor está sobre algum dos componentes e, caso não, oculta a hbox. O problema é que o evento de saída esta ocorrendo antes do evento de entrada, e assim a verificação do cursor é feita antes do boolean ser atualizado.

Comment: Pra mim não ficou claro seu propósito, em que exatamente tu quer aplicar isso? Como o método é chamado? O que você tentou (código)?

Comment: Prontinho, editado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que este seja o resultado que você quer, pelo que entendi:

```
@FXML
private Button btn;

// ...

@FXML
public void mostrarPopup(){
    Popup popup = new Popup();
    popup.setAutoHide(true);

    HBox hb = new HBox();
    Button btn2 = new Button("Botão 2");
    Button btn3 = new Button("Botão 3");
    hb.getChildren().addAll(btn2, btn3);

    popup.getContent().addAll(hb);
    Bounds bounds = btn.localToScreen(btn.getBoundsInLocal());
    // X + Width = Lado direito
    popup.show(btn, bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getMinY());

    // Fecha o popup quando o mouse sai do HBox
    hb.setOnMouseExited((MouseEvent t) -> {
        popup.hide();
    });
}
```

Basta adicionar o método mostrarPopup() no onMouseEntered do seu botão:

```
<Button fx:id="btn" layoutX="129.0" layoutY="26.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseEntered="#mostrarPopup" text="Button" />
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Este método seria para um menu, correto? Eis um problema. Eu necessito de um menu com as opções na horizontal, mas não consegui achar um método para alterar isso em um menu, por isso tentei implementar eu mesmo. Mas aí deu alguns probleminhas e pra fazer o negócio bem feito eu precisaria saber se o mouse está sobre um componente em um dado momento.

Comment: Tentou ao menos colocar um HBox dentro do contextmenu?

Comment: Tentei agora, e ele parou de expandir

Comment: Ta, mas não tem mesmo como saber se o cursor estiver sobre um componente? Tipo um método do componente que ao ser chamada retorna um boolean dizendo se o cursor está ou não sobre?

Comment: Editei com outro workaround, veja se fica melhor.